# How to generate a Randomized Complete Block Design?

Tags: r, experiment-design, blocking

I'm studying agriculture and I'm looking for answers concerning one of my problem.

I have to implement a randomized complete block design and I would like to generate it with R.

I've found some answers in the pdf of the package named "agricolae". Nevertheless, I cannot manage to create it.

Does someone have an idea on how to do this please ?

I have 6 treatments and 4 blocks..

Answer (score 3):

The `agricolae` package is useful for this task. In your case:

```
if(!require(agricolae)){install.packages("agricolae")}
library(agricolae)
treatment = letters[1:6]
design.rcbd(trt=treatment, r=4)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for :) .. By the way, do you have any idea of how can I replace the letters I obtain (a, b, c, d, e, f) by either numbers (1 -> 6) or sentences/words such as Mod1, Mod2 -> Mod 6 ?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `treatment =` line.  For numbered treatments: `treatment = 1:6`.  For custom treatments: `treatment = c("Control", "N only", "P only", "N and P only", "NPK", "NPK plus micro")`

Answer (score 0):

For an experiment it depends on what you want, do you want to analyze the data or setup the treatments into the blocks? I think you want the latter based on your question. To do this you need to allocate all 6 treatments once for each of the 4 blocks. To do this is R:

```
sample(1:6,size=6,replace=FALSE)
```

4 times to get the allocations for the 4 blocks. For me this gave:

> sample(1:6,size=6,replace=FALSE)

[1] 6 3 4 1 5 2

> sample(1:6,size=6,replace=FALSE)

[1] 5 2 4 6 3 1

> sample(1:6,size=6,replace=FALSE)

[1] 2 6 3 1 5 4

> sample(1:6,size=6,replace=FALSE)

[1] 3 6 2 1 4 5

These are the ways to allocate your treatments. Choose a numbering system for your treatments and you're good to go.